# Logging: Is there any way to split haproxy's %r parameter into several quoted strings?

Tags: logging, haproxy

Background; We want to parse invalid URLs (generated by various scanners that hit our sites). This gets really complex when URIs look like:

```
/index.html?14068'#22><bla>
/index.html?fName=\Windows\system.ini%00&lName=&guestEmail=
```

Parsing this would be a lot easier if it was possible to quote each of the three elements of the %r parameter separately. In our custom log format line we use `%{Q}r` which creates a single quote with: HTTP Verb, URI and version. Is there a way to achieve this?